# Python - add header to each tuple within a list

Tags: python

I need to iterate through each tuple within a list so every list will be transformed by adding `column_name:` pattern to each value.

```
h = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

lst = [
    ('val1', 'val1', 2226796, False), 
    ('val2', 'val2', 2227796, False), 
    ('val3', 'val3', 1000, True)
]
```

Current code:

```
for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    d = (dict(zip(q, v.split())) for v in item)
    print(d)
```

Expected result:

```
['col1:val1', 'col2:val1', 'col3:2226796', 'col4:False']
['col1:val2', 'col2:val2', 'col3:2227796', 'col4:False']
['colN:valN', 'colN:valN', 'colN:valN', 'colN:valN']
```

Comment: `[[f'{a}:{b}' for a, b in zip(h, i)] for i in lst]`?

Comment: thank you good man! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @deceze!

```
[[f'{a}:{b}' for a, b in zip(h, i)] for i in lst]
```